# Sap Lumira visualization - Is it possible to use word Cloud?

Tags: sap-lumira

I require to create a word cloud in SAP Lumira. I am using 1.31.0 version. In visualization panel, we do not have option for word cloud/tag cloud. Is there a way to build same?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I got it, It is in the complementary chart - tag cloud. Visualization block